# angular ui-router route registration

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

i tried to use nested multiple views with angular ui-router
but that's not working :

My code here :

```
App.config(['$stateProvider', function ( $stateProvider) {


    $stateProvider.state({
        "name": "app",
        "url": "/{locale:[a-z]{2}}",
        "abstract": true,
        "views": {"content": {"templateUrl": "views/front/home-1.0.0.html", "controller": "homeCtrl"}}});
    $stateProvider.state({
        "name": "app.home",
        "url": "",
        "views": {
            "content@app": {"templateUrl": "views/front/home-1.0.0.html", "controllerl": "homeCtrl"}
        }});
    $stateProvider.state({
        "name": "app.signin",
        "url": "/signin",
        "views" : {
            "content@app" : {"templateUrl": "views/front/signin-1.0.0.html", "controller": "signinCtrl"}
        }
    });
}])
```

I don't know how create the state object to my code works.

I have only one view at this time.
my Html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script src="/assets/js/App/App.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>App</h1>
    <nav>
        <a ui-sref="app.home({locale:'fr'})">{{link.home}}</a>
        <a ui-sref="app.signin({locale:'fr'})">{{link.signin}}</a>
    </nav>
     <div ui-view="content">
    </div>
</body>
```

Plunkr is here :

http://plnkr.co/edit/GOpmL5myqLKhVQBY9KOg?p=preview

Comment: any error you are getting in console? could you add you html part too.?

Comment: No i don't have console errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your current approach of rendering view. Main html will contain `<div ui-view=""></div>` which will load an parent route with a template that would contain `ui-view="content"` so the inner partial will be loading through the `views` section of `$state`.

**Code**

```
App.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state({
      "name": "app",
      "url": "/{locale:[a-z]{2}}",
      "abstract": true,
      template: '<div ui-view="content"></div>'
    });
    $stateProvider.state({
      "name": "app.home",
      "url": "/home",
      "views": {
        "content": {
          "templateUrl": "home-1.0.0.html",
          "controllerl": "homeCtrl"
        }
      }
    });
    $stateProvider.state({
      "name": "app.signin",
      "url": "/signin",
      "views": {
        "content": {
          "templateUrl": "signin-1.0.0.html",
          "controller": "signinCtrl"
        }
      }
    });
  }
])
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z0ixy13qEorTFviTiwqh?p=preview)

Comment: @user1078200 could you create plunkr for the same, so that i can digged into it

Comment: @user1078200 thanks...plunkr is down now.. I'll look at it & let you know,

Comment: do you forget me ? :)

Comment: @user1078200 ohh..so sorry..I'll fix it right now..give me 10-15 minutes please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76924/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-user1078200).

Comment: @user1078200 sorry for late reply :( does it fulfilled what you want?